# HighchartsReact changing the legend order

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to control the legend order so data2 will be displayed first from the left and then data1, without changing the order of my series objects. is there a way to do it?

[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

My legend section currently looks like that:

```
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left'
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your series in the legend manually by using `legendIndex`. For example ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.legendIndex)):

```
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'A',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 2, 4],
        marker: false,
        legendIndex: 2
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        data: [2, 3, 2, 5, 4],
        name: 'B',
        marker: false,
        legendIndex: 1
    }]
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcugtk7s/1/).